Are these cracks signs of foundation problem?
we are replacing the carpet in our relatively new house (built in 2018) and found these long cracks. I’m not sure if they are signs of foundation problem but based on the old posts on Reddit, they are normal. Can you guys take a look and give us a second opinion? I don’t have Imgur so I have attached the Google Drive links to my pictures. Please let me know if ya'll can see it and thank you in advance.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17HZgkNZJ7M9eoJB44xLp_eXXh1ddYQYO/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14f2hxSa2RI0TzXNLFwdKH5rUW6i4a7UO/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1avEPjrs_1OPSCUcZU-d44gloijUBRxsA/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B_-GS-JawMgD8AfQQIGIOXN0DpA2VxWQ/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tx5zriwaOL1Zs-Y1BTifEHoxg2nRFnUj/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WW8ZZQcGQMd3b69-GBWZ8czEOzFqXWl4/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/11xZFLv6n9pmRvNi7elIwRDBHOD4Nr9CR/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCJgkGItWfnXah-eF82RDz-MwteIa2at/view?usp=drive_link,

These Google Drive shares are not public and access has to be requested.

And it's better to edit the images into your question, though you may need to scale them down or crop them before SE will accept them.

Sorry about that. You should be able to view the images now. It's my first time using this site so please bear with me haha.

And this one: New home build - cracks in basement concrete floor

And this one: Are hairline cracks in basement concrete floor a problem if there's no water coming in?

And this one: Cracks in Walk-out Basement Slab

Those are all hairline cracks in the cement floor. Normal and nothing to worry about.

Thank you very much!
